# How to load local json file in Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have been trying to load data from a local json file.I just want to load the data from the json file and assign it to a variable.I'm trying to do this in Vue.It's may be sample or I am doing something totally wrong.If there is something wrong with my question please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

My js file:

```
import json from './ecommerce-products.json';

 var vm=new Vue({
     el:'#container',
     data(){
         return {
             items:json
         }
     }
})
```

Comment: `a local json file` - so, on the server? does the file exist? what errors do you see in the browser developer tools console? oh, wait, you can't import a json file - since a json file won't export anything ... import/export in a browser only works with javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX You can import a json file. This is perfectly valid. It's basically an object. I don't think he had any errors... his code should word.

Comment: @JamesTotty or `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` in Chrome ... so, I don't know which browser you are using

Comment: @JamesTotty - you are using `@import json from 'somefile.json'` in a browser successfully, right, before making that comment?

Comment: @JaromandaX I do it pre-compiled.

Comment: @JamesTotty - sure, **that** works, but is there any indication of a build system in the question :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry habits - I always compile my vue code / es6 :p

Comment: @JamesTotty - so do I - the problem with the question is, there's no indication if the OP is (or isn't) doing the same - I tend to assume what isn't mentioned isn't done :p ... the `var vm` in `var vm=new Vue` suggests not

Comment: @JaromandaX There is no indication of anything from the OP. :p But anyways in that case yeah it won't work natively in the browser.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes,the json file is on the server.And I'm sorry,I can't understand what you mean by "OP"

Comment: @JamesTotty you said I can import a json file but how?

Comment: @sadmansudadsaife - the OP in this case is you :p

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vuecli, placing json files under the 'public' directory,then you can use
'axios' to get them.
        this.$axios({
           method:'get',
           url:'json/test.json'
        }).then(res =>{
           this.data=res.data
        })

Comment: I'm not using vuecli.